# Node js and chart js data visualization

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, chart.js

My problem is after getting data from mysql database , I can pass the data to front end  but  even if  I try many solutions, I couldn’t use the data in chart js graphics. Can anyone share me a link or give an example about the issue?

chartdesign.js

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population (millions)",
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
            data: [] // I want to add data here
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
        }
      }
  });
```

graphPage.hbs

```
<div class="card-group" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;">


<!-- Graphs -->

<div class="card-columns" style="margin-top:50px;">


<div class="card border-light"  data-placement="top"  style=" background-color:white;">


<div class="card-body">

    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

app.js

```
 config.query('//select query part',(err,ornek)=>{

        if(err){
          res.send('/404.html');
        }
        else{ 

        req.session.ornek= ornek;
        res.render('graphPage',{user: req.session.fullname, ornek: req.session.ornek});

        }
      });
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried in form of code when you receive data for the charts. You should do that in questions itself.

Comment: @ambianBeing sorry I forgot! here is the code that I try to solve problem

Comment: You are not able to use the data that you are passing as objects to the template, because you are using handlebars. Is that your question, I am assuming?

Comment: Yes it was but yesterday I solved the problem totally. Thanks for your interest by the way.@ambianBeing